# Bind object in datasource to datagridview combobox VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, combobox, datasource

I am facing a problem in my VB.Net code.

I have an object factuurregel with the following properties:

```
Property Id As Integer
Property Medewerker As Medewerker
Property Datum As DateTime
Property Activiteit As Activiteit
Property Omschrijving As String
Property Tijd As Decimal
Property Tarief As Decimal
Property Specificatie As Boolean
Property Factureren As Boolean
Property NietFactureren As Boolean
Property Klant As FactKlant
Property Project As String
```

Another object I am using there is activiteit:

```
Property Id As Integer
Property Omschrijving As String
Property FactuurRegel As String
```

In a form, I have a datagrid, where I use following code:

```
Dim lActiviteiten As New List(Of Activiteit)
        lActiviteiten = LoadActiveiten()
        Dim dgAct As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn = DataGridUren.Columns(3)
        dgAct.DataSource = lActiviteiten
```

AND

```
loadmwlist()
        Dim dgMW As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn = DataGridUren.Columns(1)
        With dgMW
            .ValueMember = dtmw.Columns("ID").ToString
            .DisplayMember = dtmw.Columns("Naam").ToString
            .DataSource = dtmw.Copy
        End With
```

where loadmwlist fills a table.

With both codes, the combobox in the datagrid is filled correct.

The problem is, when I set the object factuurregel as datasource, only in the medewerker combobox the right value is displayed.
To be complete, the object medewerker is build like this:

```
Property Id As Integer
    Property Naam As String
```

Why is the datasource correct when I use a table as datasource for the combobox, but not when I use a list of objects?

Comment: Why are you doing this: `.ValueMember = dtmw.Columns("ID").ToString` instead of this: `.ValueMember = "ID"`?  Where are you setting the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` of `dgAct`?  I'm not sure that you know what those properties actually do, so you probably ought to read up on them.

Comment: I didn't know "ID" was enough. Changed it now en it looks fine. I also added dgAct.DisplayMember = "Omschrijving"
        dgAct.ValueMember = "Id"  and now it's working good. First time I am using objects in VB.net, after using it with C# for a while.

Answer (score 0):

jmcilhinney said:

> Why are you doing this: .ValueMember = dtmw.Columns("ID").ToString
>   instead of this: .ValueMember = "ID"? Where are you setting the
>   DisplayMember and ValueMember of dgAct? I'm not sure that you know
>   what those properties actually do, so you probably ought to read up on
>   them. –

after which I added

```
       dgAct.DisplayMember = "Omschrijving"
    dgAct.ValueMember = "Id"
```

Code is working as it should now.